# Как сделать первый символ после точки в верхний регистр

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется текст в переменной `a`:

```
a = '''sherlock holmes, study in scarlet. she baker street journal.how would you describe.'''
```

Можно ли в Python 3 перевести первый символ после точки в верхний регистр?

Comment: Например - `a[0].upper() + a[1:]` - почитайте про `upper`

Comment: [решения с regex, nltk, capitalize](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26321284/4279)

Answer (score 3):

Вот так можно перевести в верхний регистр первый символ каждого предложения:

```
a = '''sherlock holmes, study in scarlet. she baker street journal.how would you describe.'''

# разбиваем весь текст на предложения
sentences = a.split('.')

final_sentences = []
# обрабатываем каждое предложение
for sentence in sentences:
  # удаляем пробелы в конце и начале предложения
  sentence = sentence.strip()

  # если предложение пустое - переходим к следующему
  if not sentence:
    continue

  # переводим первый символ предложения в верх. регистр
  sentence = sentence.capitalize()

  final_sentences.append(sentence)

# склеимаем предложения обратно
final_text = '. '.join(final_sentences)

# добавляем точку в конец
final_text = final_text  + '.'

# Результат:
# Sherlock holmes, study in scarlet. She baker street journal. How would you describe.
print(final_text)
```

Comment: 1- `str.capitalize` не только первый символ в верхний регистр переводит, но и делает маленькими все остальные буквы (то есть это несколько больше чем автор спросил, хотя и является разумным расширением задачи и даже лучше наивного `a[0].upper() + a[1:]` (к примеру, какой символ выбрать для регистра может от позиции в слове зависеть в Unicode и `str.capitalize()` может принять это во внимание). 2- в общем случае `text.split('.')` не обязан предложения возвращать. Посмотрите: [String manipulation: capitalize first letter of every sentence](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22800401/4279)

Comment: 1) Не знал, что `capitalize` остальные переводит в нижний регистр, дельное замечание. 2) Разумеется, это большое упрощение и в реальной жизни может быть только примером.

Comment: Спасибо все получилось

Answer (score 0):

с сохранением оригинальных пробелов и др неотображаемых символов

```
def isspace(iter_text: iter) -> iter:
    '''выдать пробелы до первого значащего символа и сам символ в верхнем регистре'''
    for s in iter_text:
        if s.isspace():
            yield s  # неотображаемые символы(пробелы)
        else:
            yield s.upper()  # к верхнему регистру
            break  # до первого значащего символа

def upper_text(text: str) -> iter:
    iter_text = iter(text)
    yield from isspace(iter_text)  # первый значащий символ текста к верхнему регистру
    for s in iter_text:
        yield s
        if s == '.':  # значащий символ после '.' к верхнему регистру
            yield from isspace(iter_text)

text = ''' sherlock holmes, study in scarlet. she baker street journal.how would you describe.'''
result = ''.join(upper_text(text))
```

Comment: Спасибо все получилось