# Вывести строку заглавными буквами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, у меня есть строка:

```
stroka = input()
```

Вводные данные:

```
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
```

Как сделать так, чтобы на выходе все буквы стали заглавными?

```
QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать первый символ после точки в верхний регистр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627530/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80)

Comment: если вы строки в верхний регистр переводите для последующего сравнения без учёта регистра, то см. [How do I do a case insensitive string comparison in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551443/4279) Если что-то не ясно, спрашивайте.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте метод `upper`:

```
s = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
print(s.upper())
```

[Результат:](https://ideone.com/Bp5mwO)

> ```
> QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
> ```

Полная справка о строковых методах [доступна на сайте питона](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).