# Вывести строку с противоположным регистром

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, у меня есть строка:

```
stroka = input()
```

Вводные данные:

```
QWERTYUIOPASdfghjklzxcvbnm
```

Как сделать так, чтобы на выходе все буквы поменяли свой регистр (маленькие буквы стали большими, большие — маленькими)?

```
qwertyuiopasDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
```

Comment: Мне кажется нет смысла описывать все __стандартные встроенные__ функции для работы со строками в виде вопросов-ответов. Для этого существует документация и много других [подобных сайтов](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html)

Comment: @MaxU [в обсуждении этого вопроса, которое сейчас удалено модератором](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712703), было убедительно показано, что **такие вопросы создавать можно и нужно**. Моя цель — перенести всю официальную документацию питона на ruSO. Это лишь начало

Comment: а зачем??? По-моему лучше прикрутить к ruSO "documentation", как это сделали в английской версии и писать подобные вещи туда. PS для информации: я ваши вопросы-ответы не минусовал...

Comment: @andreymal если это будет своего рода туториал, то почему бы не объединить в один вопрос, например, все строковые методы, касающиеся преобразований регистра? Или это уже не будет соответствовать критериям хорошего вопроса?

Comment: @MaxU спрашивайте у того, кто удалил обсуждение в том вопросе, а не у меня. Сообщество одобрило такие вопросы — я делаю такие вопросы, вот и всё.

Comment: @mkkik такой вопрос нужно будет закрыть как слишком общий

Comment: @andreymal не стоит доводить до абсурда.

Comment: @NickVolynkin [в обсуждении этого вопроса, которое сейчас удалено модератором](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712703), сообщество сообщило, что не считает это абсурдом

Comment: @andreymal предлагаю обсудить всё это на Мете.

Comment: У вас еще работы ["непочатый край"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370206/how-to-get-a-list-of-built-in-modules-in-python) :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте метод `swapcase`:

```
s = 'QWERTYUIOPASdfghjklzxcvbnm'
print(s.swapcase())
```

Результат:

> ```
> qwertyuiopasDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
> ```