# Сделать первую букву каждого слова большой (заглавной)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, у меня есть строка:

```
stroka = input()
```

Вводные данные:

```
qwertyu iopasd fghjklz xcvbnm
```

Как сделать так, чтобы на выходе все слова были с заглавной буквы?

```
Qwertyu Iopasd Fghjklz Xcvbnm
```

Не какое-то одно слово после какой-нибудь точки, а **все** слова в строке.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать первый символ после точки в верхний регистр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627530/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80)

Comment: @Grundy вопрос похож, но там только после точки, а здесь нужно каждое слово

Comment: В чем принципиальное отличие?

Comment: @Grundy это никак не связанные друг с другом задачи, кроме внешней похожести. И решаются эти задачи по разному (см. мой ответ здесь)

Comment: Наоборот же: какая разница пробел/начало строки перед буквой, которую надо перевести в верхний регистр или точка?

Comment: @Grundy если напишете там универсальный ответ, который позволит делать верхний регистр не только после точки, но и после пробела, после переноса строки, табуляции, других пробельных символов, многоточия и любых других символов на усмотрение пользователя — я соглашусь с дубликатом.

Comment: @andreymal, если цель добавить "каноничные" ответы на типовые вопросы по python, то думаю имеет смысл использовать метку [python-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-faq).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Используйте метод `title`:

```
s = 'qwertyu iopasd fghjklz xcvbnm'
print(s.title())
```

Результат:

> ```
> Qwertyu Iopasd Fghjklz Xcvbnm
> ```

Comment: Почему ответ минуснули?

Comment: @Alban наверное, потому что элементарные само воросы/ответы - это не лучший способ наполнения базы знаний ruSO.

Comment: @alexolut чем это принципиально отличается от [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712703)? Автор вопроса/ответа с каких-то пор стал иметь решающее значение?

Comment: Я не минусовал, если хотите знать, но и не поощряю подобных ситуаций. Если вопрос задал новичок, то вполне неплохо дать ему ответ, который его устроит, а не слать его в гугл. Но если Вы даёте самоответ - хорошо бы при этом иметь не чрезмерно тривиальную ситуацию, которая решается одной единственной функцией. А показать, что была произведена какая-то более сложная работа. И тогда она с большей вероятность будет вознаграждена голосами.

Comment: @alexolut: голоса на ответе должны отражать только насколько хорошо ответ решает поставленную в вопросе задачу в целом и относительно других ответов в частности. Не имеет значения, кто автор вопроса/ответа. Не имеет значения насколько простая тема по вашему. Если вы считаете, что подобный вопрос неуместен на Stack Overflow голосуйте за закрытие вопроса, минусы на ответы неправильно в таком случае ставить. (я не вижу кстати минуса на ответе). Кстати, не-ascii случай может быть нетривиальным (в зависимости от версии Unicode, используемой вашей версией Питона)

Comment: @jfs голоса субъективны, а стало быть, никому ничего не должны. Если Вы считаете, что сложность темы не имеет значение - оформите вопрос типа "как сложить 2 и 2" с самоответом. Посмотрим на реакцию сообщества.

Comment: @alexolut: заставь дурака богу молиться — он себе лоб разобьёт. В крайности впадать не надо. Если нужно здравый смысл при голосовании использовать, это не значит что как угодно можно голосовать.

Comment: @alexolut `наверное, потому что элементарные само вопросы/ответы - это не лучший способ наполнения базы знаний ruSO` — на самом деле, это отличный способ наполнения базы знаний.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky но голосуют участники, а не база знаний! P.S. Ну и всё же пошёл мета-оффтоп какой-то здесь.